# how to restore under-replicated blocks to the replication factor by myself?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

how to restore under-replicated blocks to the replication factor  by myself?

I have two datanodes ,three files on them. because file is very small ,so one block one file .
the replication factor is 2,now there is only 3 under-replicated blocks in the cluster. How can I restore the blocks to 6?

thank you for your help!

Comment: With only two datanode, I do not think you can have a replication factor of more than 2.

Answer (score 1):

If there enough data nodes for the defined replicated factor - NameNode will take care to restore replication factor 
If you want it to happen just now - I think copy files will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use hadoop dfs -setrep [-R] [-w]  path/file

Comment: I tried,  I set the factor from  2 to 3. the prompt will always be wait for /input/??.txt ..... ,it wiil not reolicate the block from 1 to 3 or to 2 in my cluster